# github action pull request event is not running

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub action code with terraform and ECR, ECS now I have two branch master and feature and when I created Pull-request for `feature to master`

then only my terraform plan code will run but when i create a Pull-request and merge to master then my GitHub action running but that part is skipped i am not sure why it is happing please find the below attached code

```
---
name: "workflow"
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  cd:
    name: "Deployment"
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
  #if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
    steps:
      - name: "Checkout Code"
        uses: "actions/checkout@v2"

      - name: Set tag
        id: vars
        run: echo "::set-output name=tag::${GITHUB_REF#refs/*/}"

      - name: Configure AWS credential
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        id: login-ecr
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
          ECR_REPOSITORY: my_ecr_repi
          IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.event.head_commit.message }}
        run: |
          docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
          docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
          echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"
      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}
      - name: Terraform Init
        run: |
          cd terraform_with_ALB
          terraform init
      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: |
          cd terraform_with_ALB
          terraform fmt -check
      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: |
          cd terraform_with_ALB          
          terraform validate -no-color
      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          cd terraform_with_ALB
          terraform plan -no-color -input=false
        continue-on-error: true
```

till terraform valiate it wokring fine after that it skip terraform plan part

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `pull_request` element in the `on` section.

```
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the "master" branch
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]
```